# How to change decimal separator for numeric key in my Delphi application?

Tags: delphi

In my country the decimal separator is "**,**". One of my clients would like to have it as a "**.**" character. What should I do to change decimal separator to "**.**"?

I've tried this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DecimalSeparator := '.';
  Application.UpdateFormatSettings := True;
end;
```

But this code helps only partialy. I see the "**.**" in gird in float fields. However, when user press on numeric keybord a "**.**" key, the comma is send despite the settings.
This is problem not related to the grid, I've checked this on KeyPress event on the form.

I am using Delphi 2007, thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are on windows, try changing the decimal separator in regional settings

Comment: I want to do this programmaticaly for the scope of my application.

Comment: If this is the '.' on the numeric pad, not the one between ',' and '/' then that's standard keyboard behavior. Your keyboard driver then translates the '.' to the system-defined decimal separator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you should set `UpdateFormatSettings` to `false`! If this property is true, the `DecimalSeparator` will be reset to the Windows default one every now and then (for instance, every time you lock the workstation (using Win+L) and then unlock it again). The default value is `true`, so you need to set it to `false` when you want to override `DecimalSeparator`.

Secondly, the `DecimalSeparator` is used by Delphi routines when formatting floating-point numbers as strings (e.g. when using `FloatToStr` or  `FormatFloat`). To make the decimal separator key on the numeric keypad result in a point (`.`) and not the OS default character (which is probably either `.` or `,`), you can handle the `OnKeyPress` event:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = ',' then
    Key := '.'
end;
```

But be cautious - this will replace **all** `,` with `.`, even those inserted by the comma key on the alphabetical part of the keyboard.

A more advanced (and safer) method is to handle the `OnKeyDown` event like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
var
  msg: TMsg;
begin
  if Key = VK_DECIMAL then
  begin
    PeekMessage(msg, Edit1.Handle, WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST, PM_REMOVE);
    SendMessage(Edit1.Handle, WM_CHAR, ord('.'), 0);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Wow, setting UpdateFormatSettings to false is indeed crucial. For example, on Windows 7, the decimal separator is reset to the default when I change the screen resolution or the desktop wallpaper (!).

Answer (score 1):

What char this key maps to isn't determined by Delphi, but by the keyboard layout set in windows.

One hack would be simply replacing , by . in the OnKeyPress handler.

Else you need to somehow modify the Translation of the KeyDown/Up messages to the key press messages, but I don't know how to do that.
The Translation from virtual keys to chars happens in TranslateMessage http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644955(VS.85).aspx
So you could check the message passed in to TranslateMessage beforehand, check if it is the virtual decimal key on the numpad and then pass in a different virtual key. But everything you can do is pretty hackish.